Identify component marked R3377 in a ZVR1 [Playstation VR MB]
can anyone help me to identify a component on playstation VR1 please?
Looks like voltage reulator > Component = R3377 [what the numbers mean?]
There is no picture on TV or VR headset. [only HDMI icon]
As soon as AC Voltage is applied this component just heats up, and cooldown after 4seconds.
It is located on oposite MB side of HDMI IC ADV7626 HDMI 2:2 cross point transceiver.
Voltages [after AC is connected] on pic attached, not sure if they are correct ones for this component though.




Thank you

Not an answer, just an observation: this is the behavior I would expect if there were a downstream short (I agree with your voltage regulator assessment) and the overcurrent protection were kicking in. I.e. this component is likely operating correctly so it does not need to be replaced.

thank you a lot for the explanation and a perfect update on this! :) [Very helpful with the component identification]. Why I mentioned before that this component may be faulty is because, compared with the other working board, this component does not 'light up' at all with AC voltage applied, remains 'calm' all the time. [not heating up at all]
[unfortunetally does not have the working board now, and did not measured the values on it before :( ]

Anyway - the fault happened after a storm passed [electricity spike?] on 3 devices TV/PS4/ and this VR. The PS4 repaired with new HDMI IC. So now im just guessing same issue will be on this board and this voltage regulator could be getting weird higher voltage than it should [Pin4/ECO]? [maybe from shorted HDMI IC] All just guesses, but let me replace this one just to make sure, and if still same behaviour, than HDMI IC will be next. :) THANK YOU ALL!

Possibly OnSemi NCP585DSN33T1G - a 3.3 V LDO rated for up to 350 mA output.
Based on the datasheet linked above the part is marked with a five digit code where the first three digits are the part specific marking, R33 in this case, and the second two digits are a traceability code.


The part has the following pinout. This matches with your 5 V being Vin (pin 1), 3.3 V being Vout (pin 5), and GND (pin 2).
Pin 3 is an output enable, which being a pulled up to 3.3V makes sense as this is the active high variety. The Eco pin seems to be some internally generated bias, so a weird voltage makes sense.

The part has an upper limit of 250 mW power dissipation, which would limit the current to under 150 mA for a 5 V input. While the junction to ambient thermal information is not specified, I assume this power limit is a thermal limiting factor, so getting hot is not entirely surprising.
As long as the temperature is less than the 85 °C rated maximum operating parameter, the part should be functioning normally and this part is likely not the culprit to your incorrectly operating device. The fact that it is still successfully regulating the output to the correct level further supports that.

This answer is explained very well. One thing maybe I would note is that just because it's really hot, doesn't necessarily imply a short. LDOs are notorious for their power inefficiency.

Looking at the The ultimate SMD marking codes database for marking codes starting with R3 finds the candidate device:



Marking
Name
Manufacturer/Case
Function




R33
R1161N331D
RicohSOT-23-5
Linear voltage regulator IC LDO, 3.3V±2%, 350mA, +CE, CL, AE(Mode)



I think Ricoh is now Nisshinbo Micro Devices Inc
R1161N SERIES MARK SPECIFICATION shows the format of the marking code is:

I.e. the first 3 characters are the Product Code and the last 2 characters are the Lot Number.
I.e. the Product Code is R33 which the above document shows is R1161N331D:


The R1161N331D datasheet shows the following pin configuration for the SOT-23-5 package which seems to match that reverse engineered in the question:


Nisshinbo specialize in cheap mainstream LDO iirc, so quite likey this is a compatible device with the Onsemi one suggested in another answer.
